# Scraping Prices to Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create price tracking for a drill press in a Google Sheet. I understand how the =IMPORTXML works, but I can't figure out the right xpath.

I'm trying to use camelcamel since they have live prices.

I've tried to use Google and Firefox to copy the Xpath from the element, but the xpath I get from that doesn't work.

Here's the link: https://camelcamelcamel.com/W1680-1-Horsepower-17-Inch-Floor-Model/product/B0000DD101

=IMPORTXML("https://camelcamelcamel.com/W1680-1-Horsepower-17-Inch-Floor-Model/product/B0000DD101","????")

Comment: XML parsing might fail as you're linking a website, trying to load the URL you've suggested seems to fail. Try it here: https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer If you know it should work, you can try some extensions, for Google e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-finder/ihnknokegkbpmofmafnkoadfjkhlogph or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure i sound really ignorant, but I don't understand why linking a website would cause it to fail. I thought the formula was specifically for linking websites?

Comment: It's for structured data, like HTML is. However, where a web browser can be forgiving in mistakes or more flexible in standards, parsing might fail.. Not saying this is the case, just that trying to import it into the xmlviewer also didn't work, perhaps due some script in the header. Perhaps you can try [HTMLIMPORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339), or you could test by some simple XPath to see if that works in Google Sheets